# Problems with Plotting a Solution Curve to a Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I was using Mathematica to plot various solution curves to differential equations, and graphing them simultaneously. However, I came across a problem when graphing $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x^2 + y^2$ with $y(0) = -1$. Using the following code,

```
gensol[y0_] = DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2, y[0] == y0}, y[x], x];
Plot[y[x] /. gensol[-1], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

I get the following image
[image]

Clearly, this is not the actual shape of the curve, so I was wondering how I would fix this.

Comment: seems the same.  `sol = DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2}, y[x], x];
Plot[y[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> 5, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed, 
 Exclusions -> Automatic]`

Comment: @cvgmt I'm not quite sure what you're saying?

Comment: Consider `FunctionDomain[y[x] /. gensol[-1], x]` and see if this is better for you: `Plot[y[x] /. gensol[-1], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 Exclusions -> List @@ Simplify@Not@FunctionDomain[y[x] /. gensol[-1], x]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 The graph now changes to not have the line between (0,1) and (0,-1), but the rest of the graph stays the same as above. The required graph should just be a smooth curve.

Comment: I see. Perhaps `gensol[y0_] = {y -> Function[x, Piecewise[ {{DSolveValue[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2, y[0] == y0}, y[x], x, Assumptions -> x > 0], x > 0},  {DSolveValue[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2, y[0] == y0}, y[x], x, Assumptions -> x < 0], x < 0}}, y0] // Evaluate]}`.

Comment: With my previous comment's `gensol[]`, try ``Plot[y[x] /. gensol[-1], {x, -5, 5}, 
 Exclusions -> Join @@ FunctionProperties`Singularities[ y[x] /. gensol[-1], {x}, {"BRANCHCUTS", "DEFCUTS", "POLES", "ESSENTIAL", "IGNORE", "PWMINMAX"}]]``

Comment: @SharkyKesa Why do you assume the shape of the curve to be wrong?

Comment: @Ulrich The theory of ODEs says there should be a differentiable solution to the IVP defined in an open interval containing $x=0$.  The branch on the left is not part of the solution to the IVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives a solution to the IVP continuous in a neighborhood of the initial condition:

```
gensol[y0_] = {y -> Function[x, Piecewise[{
       {DSolveValue[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2, y[0] == y0}, y[x], x, 
         Assumptions -> x > 0], x > 0},
       {DSolveValue[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2, y[0] == y0}, y[x], x, 
         Assumptions -> x < 0], x < 0}
       }, y0] // Evaluate]};

Plot[y[x] /. gensol[-1], {x, -5, 5},
 Exclusions -> 
  Join @@ FunctionProperties`Singularities[
    y[x] /. gensol[-1], {x}, {"BRANCHCUTS", "DEFCUTS", "POLES", 
     "ESSENTIAL", "IGNORE", "PWMINMAX"}]]
```

[image]